# How to change photopath in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have total 5000 data in mysql how is it possible to change this photopath ?

my current data:

```
(photos/date/datefullname.jpg)
photos/20151117/20151117samplename.jpg
```

to:

```
(photos/applicants/date/datefullname.jpg)
photos/applicants/20151117/20151117samplename.jpg
```

adding applicants in photopath.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this:

```
UPDATE sample
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'photos/', 'applicants/')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like that

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname,'photos/date','photos/applicants/date')
```

but you should not store the url in the database as you can change the path without edit in the database

you can see this link for more explanation 
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-ways-to-insert-an-image-path-into-the-MySQL-database-and-save-it-in-the-folder-and-display-the-same-image-in-a-web-page-via-PHP/answer/Gajus-Kuizinas